# How can I protect our client database in either Windows or Access?

Tags: database, security, windows-7, ms-access-2013

I started working for a company in the field service industry. We have a program and client database build in Access. As of right now, they are scheduling their service calls in a notebook. I am trying to get this company into this era by having a web-based scheduling software.

I have basic schooling networking but I am not a programmer nor do I know Access.  I have learned how to split the database and create a multi-user environment and converted it to accdb from mdb to work with Access 2013 instead of 2003 in which it was written.  These steps have greatly helped but I am not sure where to go from here.

My next step is the scheduling software but the company's greatest concern is the protection of their client database. Not from outside hackers but there is always a concern of employees selling our client list to our competitors. Also, at this time, employees do not have web access for this reason, which they will need.

Is there any way to keep the accdb file from being sent via email etc. or copied to external media? If I set up permissions through the OS, won't that make the client files uneditable (for lack of a better word) in Access? Like address/tele # changes or notes? I'm not even sure what to even search for help.

Thank in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

I understand that Access 2013 can be installed on a Server 2008 R2 or 2012 server.  Put a password on the database.  That should keep hackers out, and as far as keeping employees out of the data that they shoudn't be in, I know the navigation bar can be hidden, but it is unfortunately able to be viewed again by the F11 key. It would've been nice if MS could have made the navigation bar ability an easy option (yes or no), and make it modifyable in VBA....They may have.  Keeping users out of raw data is something I have yet to figure out too....
I'm a novice at this stuff, but I was able to write code, and a login screen of my own so that users can have their own login ID, and a password (or phrase), and enable them to change their own password if they forget it, or if they just just to change it.  You can make the navigation bar disappear by the VBA code:    **DoCmd.LockNavigationPane True**...but unfortunately F11 can re-enable it.
Hope this helps....